# (GAE) click on the version of the service, an error 502 occurs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

App engine is in use.

If you click on the version of the service, an error 502 occurs.(appspot.com)

However, there is no problem access to the domain connected to the service.

I want to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be and issue with the GAE traffic in Asia, which is probably related to your error. The Google engineering team is investigating it with high priority.

Answer (score 0):

For server issues that doesn't involve a potential coding/configuration error on your end, please use our [issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/). You can report all potential bugs / feature requests there, thanks.